# Need help in Face Detection using C# language

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, face-detection, face-recognition

I am working on the **face recognition** project for tracking the people who come across the gate. It will keep log of the people who passes through the door. 
 I am using **EmguCV**, in **C#** language. And I am using here **Haarcascade xml** file for face detection. But I think it is not enough good. So kindly suggest me another way to detect faces efficiently using C# language.

Comment: I'm afraid requests for libraries, etc. are not on topic on Stack Overflow. You may have to just search around on the Internet.

Comment: you shouldn't ask for tools on stack overflow. there are other sites for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Project Oxford Face API](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/face-api)

Very simple in use. It's not free for commercial projects, but you can use limited trial edition

Here is a manual:

[Getting Started with Face API in CSharp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt605323.aspx)